# query work on MySQL Workbench but in node.js is return problem with syntax

Tags: mysql, node.js

I need some help, When i make this query in workbench its work fine

```
INSERT INTO reports(creatorUserID,currentUserEditorID,companyID,stageID,scenarioID,typeID,year)  VALUES (1,1,456545,1,1,1,1500);
INSERT INTO reports_tax_data(reportID,data) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'work perfect');
```

but when i do the same things in nodejs

```
const createNewReport = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query(
      `INSERT INTO reports(creatorUserID,currentUserEditorID,companyID,stageID,scenarioID,typeID,year)  VALUES (1,1,456545,1,1,1,1500);
       INSERT INTO reports_tax_data(reportID,data) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'work perfect');`,
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(result);
      }
    );
  });
};
```

i get this error:

```
 sqlMessage:
   'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'INSERT INTO reports_tax_data(reportID,data) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),\'work perfe\' at line 2',
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql:
   'INSERT INTO reports(creatorUserID,currentUserEditorID,companyID,stageID,scenarioID,typeID,year)  VALUES (1,1,456545,1,1,1,1500);\n        INSERT INTO reports_tax_data(reportID,data) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),\'work perfect\');' }
```

But when i make a normal select its work in nodejs

Comment: try to make your queries seperatly. First insert into reports and then insert into reports_tax_data. It is possible that the package you're working with doesn't support executing multiple queries at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

I would assume here that the Node SQL API you are using does not allow more than one statement to be executed per call (this is certainly the case for a few other programming languages).  Try making separate calls for each insert:

```
connection.query(
  `INSERT INTO reports(creatorUserID,currentUserEditorID,companyID,stageID,scenarioID,typeID,year)  VALUES (1,1,456545,1,1,1,1500)`,
  (err, result) => {
    if (err) reject(err);
    resolve(result);
  }
);
```

And do the same for the `reports_tax_data` table insert.

Answer (score 3):

i think you have to set a below mention configuration to allow multiple queries on node js.

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true});
```

please check and comment if any issue.